# Flot chart eliminate selected colour

Tags: javascript, flot

I have a well working stacked area chart using Flot. It's fill colours currently are auto-generated.

My question is, is it possible for me to eliminate selected colours. Meaning, I don't want the chart to be using green, red and orange as a fill colour.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The `API` does not provide a way to `exclude` some color if it's
>   ***`auto-generated`***

<s>I think you could easily edit the [`jquery.colorhelpers.js`](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md) file and comment/remove the `auto-colors` you don't want.</s>

Like for example <sup>(untested)</sup>

```
var lookupColors = {
        aqua:[0,255,255],
        azure:[240,255,255],
        beige:[245,245,220],
        black:[0,0,0],
        // blue:[0,0,255], // --> no blue
        brown:[165,42,42],
        cyan:[0,255,255],
        ...
    };
```

***Edit:***
If you're ***not*** manually including the `jquery.colorhelpers.js` file, please note the author comment in [`jquery.flot.js`](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/jquery.flot.js) file on line 8:

```
8: // first an inline dependency, jquery.colorhelpers.js, we inline it here
9: // for convenience
```

*the inline code is on line 32:*

```
32: (function($){$.color={};$.color.make=...
```

---

***Edit 2:***

> **Important Clarification**

After read a bit the code and author's comments in [`jquery.flot.js`](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/jquery.flot.js) file, I realize that the above suggestion was completely wrong...
The `lookupColors` var is used to match a `given` color name with with corresponding `RGB` value...
***Nothing to do with the auto-generated colors for the chart.***

Now... In the same reading, I found out this `color theme` declaration <sup>jquery.flot.js line 516</sup>

```
516: // the color theme used for graphs
517: colors: ["#edc240", "#afd8f8", "#cb4b4b", "#4da74d", "#9440ed"],
```

And guess what... If you modify it.. will change the chart, so I think this will be your best approach.

Example:

```
colors: [
    // "#edc240", // --> this removes/disabled the dark-yellow
    "#afd8f8",
    "#cb4b4b",
    "#4da74d",
    "#9440ed"
],
```

So now, you're not only able to `exclude` some color, you're also able to create your own `theme`.
nice ;)

jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/gmolop/9u8tsfum/

Comment: but right now my html is not even linked to jquery.colorhelper.js which means the color is def auto-generated in the main script itself. which also means there is no way i can exclude selected colours.

Comment: Are you including `jquery.flot.js` file?

Comment: Please see the second edit note for an important clarification, a possible solution and an jsfiddle example.